How do graphing calculators like desmos know if there is a valid point inside the pixel?
I imagine it's going pixel by pixel and checking if the equation is true on that pixel, but here's where the problem comes. For example, if I input x^2+y^2=625, desmos will give a perfect circle, however, on my graph, there are many gaps and the circle is not connected at all. This is because the point is not in the exact coordinates of the pixel. EX: the equation is satisfied at (1, 1.5), however, it is not satisfied at the point (1,1) which is where it's the graph is checking, so the pixel is turned off when it should be on due to the fact that the equation is satisfied somewhere within that pixel. So, how do I check if the equation is satisfied somewhere within the range (in this case a 1x1 square), rather than just at the exact pixel coordinates?

No idea how they do it, but here's an idea: 1) Rearrange the formula so it's zero on the right - x^2+y^2-625 = 0 in your case.  2) Evaluate the left side at all four corners of the pixel.  3) If the results don't all have the same sign, then the true line of the equation passes through the pixel somewhere - paint it.

yes that worked perfectly thank you!
